# http get request returns different values in curl than it does in ionic2/angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

When I do a get request with curl like this:

```
curl https://api.backand.com:443/1/objects/todos?AnonymousToken=my-token
```

I am returned the correct information:

```
{"totalRows":2,"data":[{"__metadata":{"id":"1","fields":{"id":{"type":"int","unique":true},"content":{"type":"string"}},"descriptives":{},"dates":{}},"id":1,"content":"the first todo!"},{"__metphilipphpphilipphilip"}]}
```

but when I do the same request in angular 2 like this:

```
this.http.get('https://api.backand.com:443/1/objects/todos?AnonymousToken=my-token').map(res => {
  return res.json();
});;
```

I am returned a strange object called observable that looks something like this:

[image]

Why isn't the request working in angular?

Comment: `return res.json().data;` try it

Comment: where and how do you subscribe to it?

Comment: Thanks, tried adding data but it doesn't work.  I get the same thing.  what do you mean subscribe?  i'm just trying to do a simple get request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about Curl, but HTTP calls in Angular 2 return **observables**, so you need to use RxJS methods to operate on them. In order to get the response, you need to subscribe to it so that you can *observe* values that are returned.

```
 this.http.get('https://api.backand.com:443/1/objects/todos?AnonymousToken=my-token')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => this.myData = data,
      err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
```